# Cors Issue when accessing steam API Vue Axios

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, cors

im new to Vue but i'm trying to just get some details from the steam api around csgo. When I try and bring in the data it comes up with a *405 (Method Not Allowed)* on the api url and also *response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.*

I can't seem to get around this, ive trying using some online proxies and putting there url's before the steam api but no luck.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

```
<template>
        <div>
            <ul v-if="posts && posts.length">
                <li v-for="post of posts">
                    <p><strong>{{post.steamID}}</strong></p>
                    <p>{{post.stats}}</p>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul v-if="errors && errors.length">
                <li v-for="error of errors">
                    {{error.message}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios';

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                posts: [],
                errors: []
            }
        },

        // Fetches posts when the component is created.
        created() {
            axios.get(`http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?appid=730&key=52828DE98A6C45A556BF4E5AF4F3CF1D&steamid=76561197980619010`)
                .then(response => {
                    // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
                    this.posts = response.data
                })
                .catch(e => {
                    this.errors.push(e)
                })

            // async / await version (created() becomes async created())
            //
            // try {
            //   const response = await axios.get(`http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`)
            //   this.posts = response.data
            // } catch (e) {
            //   this.errors.push(e)
            // }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It seems `api.steampowered.com` is not your own server, you can't change the configuration for CORS. so you may have to build one reverse proxy or send your request to your backend server, then let the backend call that URL.

Answer (score 0):

This is part of your web browser and your web server.

It basically stops malicious attacks, e.g.

1. You visit `my-innocent-blog.com` and it has a "Like my website" button
2. You click it, and it sends a request to StackOverflow to delete your account.
3. StackOverflow servers receive the DELETE request, with the origin being `my-innocent-blog.com`, and it tells your web browser "That request should only originate from our own website".
4. Your web browser says "Okay, I'll ignore the request and throw a CORS error"

Thus protecting you from accidentally being tricked into deleting your account (or worse).

If you're using an ExpressJS server, check out their CORS package.
https://github.com/expressjs/cors

Otherwise, just search " CORS" on Google and you'll find something for pretty much everything.